# How can I subclass a class loaded from a swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to subclass "superClass" and override one of it's functions.

```
public class superClass {
    protected function f1(...) : Boolean {...}
    protected function f2(...) : Boolean {...}
    ...
    protected function f100(...) : Boolean {...}
}
public class subClass extends superClass {
    // override f1 in the subclass
    protected override function f1(...) : Boolean {...}
}
```

The problem is that the "superClass" is loaded from a swf. I do not have a reference to the class definition in my project. Is there a way to do something like below?

```
public class subClass {
    private var superClassObject:  Object;

    // construct from an instance of superClass
    public function subClass (s : Object) {
        superClassObject = s;
    }

    private function myF1(...) : Boolean {...}

    override InvokeFunction (fname: string, args: Array) : Object {
        if (fname == "f1") {
            return myF1(args);
        } else {
            return superClassObject.InvokeFunction(fname, args);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how function call is implemented in AS. What should "InvokeFunction" be?

Comment: You need a reference to the class definition in order to subclass it at compile time. Otherwise, you're asking the compiler to subclass nothing.... your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Use 'super()' keyword in constructor of subclass

Answer (score 0):

You should use .swc , not .swf. The class you want to extend must be available at compile time, not at runtime. Anyway if using of swf is mandatory for you, you could use different techniques to 'override' functionality.
Besides inheritance there are other OOP concepts (`Composition, Aggregation`,etc...) and design patterns(`Proxy,Adapter`,etc...) for changing functionality of class. You could use them.